# generate statistics from opentracing measures

Tags: spring-boot, opentracing, jaeger

I have activated **opentracing** on my Spring Boot micro-service application using **Jaeger** as a collector and it all works fine. I manage to get a full trace of my calls from different components, it is very useful to understand the calls to the application.

Now, in the scope of performance testing, I need to generate statistics from the different readings. That is e.g. average time of traces during a time period or number of occurrences of a specific span.

Is there any tool to achieve that? Is there a standard query language/api/tool to allow to extract big numbers of opentracing metrics?

Answer (score 0):

Jaeger has a UI to look at your data, but no tools to create statistics. However all your data is being stored in a DB of your choice. Storing it in e.g. Elasticsearch gives you a powerful query language to look at the data as well as many other tools that integrate with it.